# Excel Formula to Count Values between Dates

Tags: excel

I am looking for a way to count how many companies are in Column C on the specific dates of column A. Can one formula be applied to the count between all of dates?

I have tried looking up and using =CountBlanks and I do not want to have to manually select the cell ranges between the dates.

Ultimately I am also trying to put this data into a table so I can see on Feb 16 = 3 Companies, Feb 19 = 5. I can not use a VBA script as some users have macros blocked.

Please look at image for example
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N1jC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=COUNTA(INDEX($C$2:$C$21,MATCH($E2,$A$2:$A$21,0)):INDEX($C$2:$C$21,MIN(IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($A$2:$A$21>$E2,0),0),9999999),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($C$2:$C$21="",0),0))-1))
```

[image]

Change the 21s in the formula to at least the extent of your data +1, It can be more,  Full column references will not work due to the Word "Date" in the first row.

Comment: Thanks Scott! That is quite the formula.

Comment: @StrikeMidnight if it worked pleas mark as correct, by clicking on  the grey-green check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIF( start_date, end_date, interval )

you didnt even bother to google this, right?

edit: there should be enough common place stuff like isblank to accommodate the lack of values. If youre trying to find the values between A & C then you can easily adjust your formula accordingly.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking, did you read the OP.  He wants the number of companies per date not the time between dates.